# $_GET array is always empty after facebook app authentication 

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I am trying to play around with authentication for an app I am working on atm. The app will be tab based. I am now strugling with an infinite loop while trying to authenticate the app. The authentication procces is like this:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
            $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
            $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
                    . $appId . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirectUri) . "&state="
                    . $_SESSION['state'];

            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
            exit;
        }

        if ($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
            $code = $_GET["code"];
            $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                    . "client_id=" . $appId . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirectUri)
                    . "&client_secret=" . $appSecret . "&code=" . $code;

            $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
            $params = null;
            parse_str($response, $params);

            $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
                    . $params['access_token'];

            $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
            echo("Hello " . $user->name);
        } else {
            echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
        }
```

The $redirectUri is now set to "http://www.facebook.com/pages/DummyPage/PAGE_ID?sk=app_APP_ID" but once I am redirected back, after the authentication, I am unable to read $_GET or $_REQUEST arrays because they are empty (even though I can see that the url I get after auth. has "code", "state" etc. in it). This will result in infinite loop, because I am stuck in the first if statement.

What is interesting here is that when I change the $redirectUri to the url where my app sits in - right now I am testing it on localhost - so I put in "http://localhost/test/index.php" - the infinite loop wont happen because I am redirected outside facebook and I can read from $_GET array.

I need to stay on facebook when authenticating. Do you guys know how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) for things that you're trying right now.

It makes the thing a lot easier and you probably get to your goal in less time.

OR

if you want to do manually and interested in learning the internals, you need to check [page tab authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/) and [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Comment: So i switched the authentication to php sdk and it worked better. The whole redirecting now works and I stay on facebook.